# PEAR installed but not working. Where is PEAR.php?

Tags: email, pear, php, pyrus

I've installed PEAR using `pyrus.phar` in `C:\PEAR` for PHP on IIS7. I've also downloaded the PEAR Mail package when I `require_once` the file `Mail.php`, I get `HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error`.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    set_include_path('C:/PEAR/php');
    require_once 'Mail.php'; //should give me a blank page but is giving me an error
?>
```

I checked in Mail.php there is a line `require_once 'PEAR.php';`

Now where do I get this PEAR.php from?

Comment: What is inside in the 'C:/PEAR/php'

Comment: If you open cmd and execute this:pear config-get php_dir, what is the output of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the old pear installer, too:

```
$ pyrus install pear/pear
```

It provides `PEAR.php`.